# Web Fonts on Mac appear different to Windows

Tags: css, macos, fonts

I've chosen to use one of the many Google Web Fonts as the main font for my website. The website is being displayed on both a Mac and Windows computer yet the font appears slightly different in terms of their dimensions and spacial conformations on the page.

[image: Demonstration of different outcomes]

[Link to the Google Font](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lato)

The code in the CSS to apply the font is:

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

just like how the font website suggests embedding the font into the website. (Also the font is linked within the header file as required).

The web browser I am using is Chrome in both instances, however the results stay the same if I use Safari on Mac or Firefox on Windows or any other assortment of browsers. It seems to be a system level thing going on here.

What options do I have to go about fixing this so that I can still use a Google Web Font for my website?

Comment: Different browser and operating system combinations render fonts slightly differently. I don't think there's much you can do about it except provide ample room for variations.

Comment: Welcome to the world of font rendering. Didn't you see the sign at the entrance that said "not pixel perfect"?

Comment: same problem, linux vs windows ; my font padding is needed on linux, not on win... have to write 2 css...

Answer (score 6):

Try to use:

```
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

That helped me in my case to make fonts on Mac and Windows looks the same.